# ImageView: changing set of imageviews src by generic code

Tags: android

I have set of 26 imageviews and set of 26 images( named as a... z), I am trying to set a random image to each imageview one by one by generic code.
Getting a runtime error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    initialMethod(); 
    //this method loads the random images to imageview one by one
}   

 public void initialMethod() {

  String temp;
  TextView mytextView;
  int randList[] ={26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
  ImageView myImageView;       
  int ImageViewIdList[] = {R.id.imageA1, R.id.imageA2, R.id.imageA3, R.id.imageA4, R.id.imageA5, R.id.imageA6, R.id.imageA6, R.id.imageA8, R.id.imageA9, R.id.imageA10, R.id.imageA11, R.id.imageA12, R.id.imageA13, R.id.imageA14, R.id.imageA15, R.id.imageA16, R.id.imageA17, R.id.imageA18, R.id.imageA19, R.id.imageA20, R.id.imageA21, R.id.imageA22, R.id.imageA23, R.id.imageA24, R.id.imageA25, R.id.imageA26};

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        myImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(ImageViewIdList[i]);
        String ImageName = String.valueOf((char) (randList[i] + 97));            
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(ImageName, "id", getPackageName());
        myImageView.setImageResource(id);           
    }
```

Comment: Can you share which line throws the runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all - always post your error. You're trying to load an ID as an image resource. Instead, put your drawable IDs in randList.

Also consider creating all those ImageViews dynamically in the code, as well as other proper coding practices (e.g. no hard coded values in code and so on, though I bet this is for a school exercise)

```
int randList[] = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ... }
imageView.setImageDrawable(randList[...]);
```

Comment: "Unfortunately The "MyABC" has stopped" is the error msg in handy

Comment: Thanks now I understood what you said

Comment: You can see the real error message in ADB Logcat, in Android Studio click Android Monitor in the bottom. Check my edits soon for code.

Comment: If the answer helped you please check it correct to help others!

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped one of your commas with ' between 17 and 16

Change:

```
int randList[] ={26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17'16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
```

to:

```
int randList[] ={26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
```

Comment: sorry it is my typing mistake here only

Comment: $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.android.myabc/com.example.android.myabc.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 18717 on device samsung-gt_i8190-4790723a36b310da
Application terminated.

Answer (score 0):

try this way...

```
    int randList[] ={26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    ImageView myImageView;
    int ImageViewIdList[] = {R.id.imageA1, R.id.imageA2, R.id.imageA3, R.id.imageA4, R.id.imageA5, R.id.imageA6, R.id.imageA6, R.id.imageA8, R.id.imageA9, R.id.imageA10, R.id.imageA11, R.id.imageA12, R.id.imageA13, R.id.imageA14, R.id.imageA15, R.id.imageA16, R.id.imageA17, R.id.imageA18, R.id.imageA19, R.id.imageA20, R.id.imageA21, R.id.imageA22, R.id.imageA23, R.id.imageA24, R.id.imageA25, R.id.imageA26};

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        myImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(ImageViewIdList[i]);
        String ImageName = String.valueOf((char) (randList[i] + 97));            
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(ImageName, "id", getPackageName());
    }
```

Comment: what is the change I couldnt find, could you please tell your suggestion

Comment: there is issue in this randList

Answer (score 0):

As **"etan"** said
I have changed the code 
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(randList[i],"id", getPackageName());

to

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(randList[i],"drawable", getPackageName());

Thanks a lot etan! :)